# Skewed t-distribution in python

Tags: python, random, statistics, distribution, scipy.stats

Python has `scipy.stats.t` which can generate random numbers (`rvs`) and fit the parameters (`fit`) that follow the t-distribution, but is there something similar in python for fitting and generating a skewed-t distribution?

If not, can `scipy.stats.t` be modified somehow to be the skewed t?

Comment: In general you have to code up the probability density function and run it through a numerical optimization routine.  Otherwise you could transform the data to remove the skew and fit a standard t distribution.  Another option would be to calculate moments of your data (e.g. mean, SD) and use them to calculate parameters of your distribution

Comment: I came across the following skew normal t function for R. Has it been adapted to python as well? https://rdrr.io/cran/sn/man/dst.html